# Display table-cell gets extra unwanted width

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="#" class="six columns push_two contact-form">
    <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="email" name="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Phone number</span>
        <input type="text" name="phone" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Message</span>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And CSS:

```
label{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid $grey_dark 1px;
}
span{
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input, textarea{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In result I get something like the screenshot bellow. I have marked the spans with red border. They wider than I want. I did not set any width, margin or padding to them. But still they are wider. Can you give me a solution to this so that the spans become the size of the text width.
[image]

I want something like bellow:
[image]

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the OP's code http://jsfiddle.net/102rz6dd/

Comment: Can't you set a width to the spans? As in set the same width for all of them so they line up. I assume that's what you are after

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a table row, for table cells to behave.  Try this:

```
form {display: table;}
label{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid $grey_dark 1px;
}
```

Updated answer:

```
label{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid #333 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input, textarea{
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Did not help me with what I want. If I use table, table-row and table-cell, then all the spans get same width (the widest one). I want variable width to each span.

Comment: Then you don't want a table.  Table cells in the same column are always the same width by default.

Comment: You might try a div here, and put the span inside that.  Not quite sure what you're asking for now, but another container inside the table-cell will probably give you enough flexibility to do whatever.

Comment: Yeah I don't see a table there at all.  Maybe set your spans to display:inline-block; and set the correct width for each one.

Comment: The whole form is not a table. I cannot achieve it like that. That is why I set each of the labels as a table. P.S. Setting up width for each element is not a solution for me in this case.

Comment: Updated my answer.  This gets you pretty close, and no table.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the display as table for span you need to use **table-row**.

```
label{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid $grey_dark 1px;
}
```